# django 1.5 flips between "it worked" page display and error 500

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Installed Django 1.5 python2.7 mod_wsgi and python-sql on a red hat 4 web server with apache 2.
The "It worked" page keep flipping between the correct display and "internal server error" "500"

The flip occurs very frequently when pressing F5, but not only when quickly sending a request.

I have restarted Apache, erased wsgi that was configured for python 3.2 and reconfigured and installed for 2.7.  I have also tried creating a new project, mysql database, and kicking the cat < not advisable.

On the python 3.2 installation I was having problems with the admin page registrations flipping between what I had applied, and being non-existent.

This error is occurring with debug = true, no apps installed, no database configuration yet, and what I assume is a complete baseline system aside from the wsgi file which seemed to work fine for the 3.2 installation.

Comment: when it throws 500, what is the error you get?

Comment: on the page all I'm getting is 'Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.'

Comment: interesting. would this help?http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/additionally-a-500-internal-server-error-error-was-encountered-while-trying-to-use-a-336062/  - I m quite sure it is a non-django error

Comment: Checked /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log
Apparently I still had a config somewhere for .python-egg-cache that is now non-existent.  I recreated the file and the problem was solved

Comment: Scratch last, error still occurring.  Apache logs are saying "  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/cache/python-egg-cache'"
"Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?"

I can't figure out what user needs to access the directory, www didn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting issues with the Python egg cache, see the mod_wsgi documentation at:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Access_Rights_Of_Apache_User

The reason it flicks may be because you are running a multiprocess configuration and so requests can go to different processes. That it would be different though for different processes is a bit odd, but is often explained by import order dependencies in your code where whether it works depends on the order in which URLs are visited.

Quite often such ordering issues don't show up if using Django and developing with Django developer server, because the Django development server preloads code before requests are handled. I have commented on this specific Django issue in:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html

Do note that code examples in that corresponded to an old Django version so may not be appropriate to use now.